# Rails Assets:Precompile Failure, Invalid CSS

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap-3

When running

```
rake assets:precompile
```

I get the following error:

"Invalid CSS after "...it-box-shadow: ": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ":inset 0 -1px 0..."

The offending css is in bootstrap.css:

```
.form-control {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 34px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  color: #555555;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
          box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s;
  transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s;
}
```

This setting is all throughout the bootstrap.css file and was taken from a WrapBootstrap theme. The syntax appears correct, so I can't understand why the precompile is failing.

application.css.scss:

```
*
*= require jquery.ui.all
*= require bootstrap
*= require animations
*= require font-awesome
*= require font-awesome-ie7
*= require graph
*= require ie
*= require nivo-slider
*= require prettyPhoto
*= require pricing-table
*= require settings
*= require style
*= require spectrum
*= require superfish
*= require switcher
*= require team-member
*= require theme-responsive
*= require colors/red
*= require video-js
*= require_self
*/

.contact{
  padding-top: 50px;
}
```

Am I missing something or is this not valid syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When adding your bootstrap gem you should specify the version. The version you have installed is likely not the same as the bootstrap CSS being used. Bootstrap changes all the time.

As a side note, run rake assets:clean && rake assets:precompile

Comment: Is it necessary to install the Gem if I've included the bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js within the appropriate stylesheet and js directory? I have been running rake assets:clean before running the precompile.

Comment: The appropriate directory would be under vendor. Then include *= require bootstrap.js in your application.js file as above but put the entire file name

Comment: Update: I have removed bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js, added bootstrap-sass v 3.0.3.0, bundle, removed all old files from repo, rake assets:clean, rake assets:precompile, and the problem still persists.

Comment: I went through a series of changes and I'm not sure what was the solution. I was frustrated and just started doing a bunch of stuff in a non-sequntial order, but it's now working. I think I've narrowed it down to one of two things, you might be able to tell me which one is the culprit. It's either past precompiled assets that were pushed to Git. I removed all assets from public. OR it was version issue with Modernizr. Either way your suggestion led me to look at the versions of Modernizr. Could Modernizr's version be the issue?

Comment: That would depend on the name of the file that is giving you the error. When compiling and it sends the error see which file the css error is in. If its in a bootstrap css file then its bootstrap. For this problem, is it a new css file your trying to add? Or are you just trying to get it to work for the first time?

Comment: Just trying to get it working for the first time.  Everything was running fine in dev in the browser. It was when I pushed to Heroku where I discovered the problem with the precompile. I just found it interesting that the bootstrap file was crapping out since I made no modifications to it. Either way, it's working now. I'm just curious as to what caused it. Thanks for the help.